# Document is not defined (expressjs)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

IM triying to put a queryselector inside a expressjs but not works

```
 // search products
        router.post('/search', function(req, res) {
            var db = req.db;
      var elasticlunr = require('elasticlunr');
              var range = require("range");



  var search_term  =document.querySelectorAll("#INPUT_8").value;
```

please give me a hand (im using nedb database )

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That is because node.js is a server side scripting environment, as opposed to a client side scripting environment on a webpage.

To access elements of the DOM in node.js you would want to use something like cheerio.js, which would require you to load your HTML into it:
https://cheerio.js.org/

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio'),
    $ = cheerio.load('<h2 class = "title">Hello world</h2>');

$('h2.title').text('Hello there!');
$('h2').addClass('welcome');

$.html();
```

Answer (score 0):

Express is server-side, it can't read from your client document. If you want to use a parameter you will have to pass it to the path either via path params, query, or in the payload.
http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.params